# GA4: Why is the session count much lower when I select 'source' or 'source/medium' as dimension in rows

Tags: google-analytics-4

In the explore tab I am trying to look at the sessions by source or source/medium.

Without selecting any dimensions, I see 670k session over a selected time period.
[total sessions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RGNX.png)

Wenn I select source I only see 2.7k sessions in the Totals. Same applies to source/medium.
[sessions by source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BovzI.png)

Can anybody tell me what might be causing this?

I expect to see how the 670k sessions are distributed over the different sources in the report.

Comment: Whenever you're debugging your analytics reports, always show your dimensions, metrics, filters (as set up on the left of the explorer) and date ranges. Please update the screenshots.